# android - using SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on a project where I need to store multiple sessions. When a user logs in the system, his username is stored in the app. So the next time app is run, the username is displayed on the home screen. He can either click on that or add new account, which then would get populated in the list too. I read the notepad tutorial on android developers website to learn how to use SQLite in android, but I couldn't make it work for my case.

I am storing the username in a string variable 'value' and I want this 'value' to be added in the database and displayed as a list on the screen. 
Can anyone please help me on this? IF you could give some links of tutorials that do exactly what I am trying to do, that would help too. Thanks!

Comment: Check it out this link...
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: vogella's article is superb but for a beginner its very confusing.. after all dats what I felt.

Comment: I have already seen the vogella article. I too feel its a bit confusing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare this first

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
```

to create table

```
 this.db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("filestore", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 this.db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usernames(name text)");
```

insert

```
String username;
db.execSQL("insert into usernames values ('"+username+"')");
```

retrieve

```
this.db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("filestore", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db_results = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM usernames", null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            db_results.add(String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("name"))));
            // db_results.add(String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"))));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
```

This tutorial from [markana](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/55.html) helped me to grab the basics of the sqlite and android. Hope it'll help you too.

another [example](http://androidbysravan.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-sqlite-basics-creating-and.html), and [one more](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742) too